# Ember.js: Component attribute not reset while testing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, acceptance-testing, ember-testing

I am currently attempting an acceptance test on a nested route, which makes use of the same component twice, but with different arguments. This works fine when I run it normally, however as I run the acceptance test, I notice that the component's arguments aren't being updated, which causes my test to fail. Here is some sample code:

In `index.hbs` I have:

```
{{index-view model=model type='location'}}
```

My `index-view` component looks like this:

```
<h1>{{title}} List</h1>

{{listing-table model=model type=type}}
```

By clicking on an element in the `listing-table`, I then go to the `locations.show` route, which contains a `link-to` the `locations.show.devices` route. The `locations.show.devices` route contains:

```
{{listing-table model=model.devices type='device' exclude='locationName'}}
```

However, in my acceptance tests, I can see (by echoing out these attributes in the component's javascript) that while `model` and `type` are being updated, `exclude` is always set to whatever was set when the component was initially called.

Now, I have checked (via `console.log()`) whether the component is being reused or not, and I could see that both `init ()` and `didDestroyElement ()` are called twice, which means that the component goes through an entire lifecycle twice. However, I can't really understand why my `exclude` argument is not being updated at all, and why does this only happen while acceptance testing?

[This is a stripped down version of what I'm doing](https://ember-twiddle.com/d9de007c02765d2f815e5a75c33d37ec?openFiles=tests.acceptance.list-locations-test.js%2C&route=%2Flocations%2F1%2Fdevices) (of course it works on Twiddle, but not in real life!).

Comment: Can you paste in your component in question? It sounds like something is out of whack with your specific component...

Comment: Not sure if this will fix the issue, but state can be shared if you set a property's default to an array or object. It looks like you're doing both that _and_ resetting the defaults in `init()` so I'm not sure if that's what's causing the issue. Here's more info on sharing state: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19071065/916734

Comment: @acorncorn: [here](https://gist.github.com/finferflu/f4832e7dd6e3bcc78bbe5a0abfd87ee3) is my component's js.

Comment: @PatrickBerkeley, if I reset the property in the `init()`, wouldn't that go against what I'm trying to do? I.e. wouldn't it just unset the property right after I've set it in my template?

Comment: @finferflu yup. So I would either not initialize the attrs in your js file or initialize them to `attr: null` outside of init() if you want to be explicit about the attrs used by the component.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not initialising the `exclude` attribute at all, it's just being passed to the component as an argument as you can see from the example above. I'm then only accessing the attribute via `this.get('exclude')` inside the component's javascript.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a git repo with a full reproduction?

Comment: OK, I'll work on that and post it here when it's ready, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
{{listing-table model=model.devices type='device' exclude='locationName'}}
```

you pass certain value `"locationName"` ( string ) not link to the property `.locationName` of component . ( I'm about quotes around `locationName` )

You know, yes?

Comment: Yes, it's intended to be just a string. In my component (see [here](https://gist.github.com/finferflu/f4832e7dd6e3bcc78bbe5a0abfd87ee3#file-listing-table-js-L73)), I then transform that string into an array.

Comment: @finferflu I'm about your question 'while model and type are being updated, exclude is always set to whatever was set when the component was initially called.'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but the `exclude` argument is supposed to be a string and not an object.